# Correctly reload partial view in .net core using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

The goal here is to have the tasking accordion card be fully reloaded/refreshed after the ajax request for creation goes through so that the next one can be created from anew. I have gotten it "working" to the point that everything else is reloaded but the name, tier, and instructions. Here is a photo of the reloaded result(bbbbb and Four are the old value used to create the last Tasking).
[the result of the partial is reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj65g.png). The name is supposed to be test with tier being Two.

When the partialView is called after the ajax call, i have checked that the new viewModel is indeed passed back with TaskingName set to test and tier set to two, and the workitem list being populated. I just dont understand why the primitive values are still showing up as the last values.Thanks

Heres my controller action responsible for returning the partial view

```
public ActionResult CreateTasking(TaskingTemplateModel viewmodel)
        => return PartialView("_TaskingTemplate", new TaskingTemplateModel { TaskingName = "test", TaskingTier = "Two", WorkItems = viewmodel.WorkItems });
```

Heres my ajax request, cardBody is the div container for which the content needs to be refreshed

```
$('.create-for-parent').click((e) => {
  $.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success(data) {
      cardBody.html(data);
    },
    error() {
      alert('couldnt refresh the view');
    },
  });
});
```

Heres the html code for the partial itself

```
<form id="create-tasking" action="/Workflow/CreateTasking" method="post" class="validate-submit">
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                @Html.TextBoxGroupFor(m => m.TaskingName, new { @class = "h5" }, new { @class = "form-control flex-fill" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                @Html.DropdownGroupFor(m => m.TaskingTier, Model.TierOptions, new { @class = "h5" }, new { @class = "form-control flex-fill" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                @Html.TextAreaGroupFor(m => m.Instructions, 2, 12, new { @class = "h5" }, new { @class = "form-control flex-fill" })
            </div>
            <!--Task-->
            <div class="mb-2">
                <h5 class="d-inline-block">Subtaskings</h5>
            </div>
            <table id="subtaskings-table" class="table table-medium table-hover">
                <thead class="bg-info">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Potential Subtaskings</th>
                        <th>Work Order</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <partial name="_WorkTable" for="@Model.WorkItems" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Finally, heres the viewmodel

```
public string TaskingName { get; set; }
public string TaskingTier { get; set; }
private string _instructions;
public string Instructions { get => _instructions; set => _instructions = value?.Trim(); }
public List<TableEntryModel> WorkItems { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how do you custom Html helper, but I reproduce the issue by using the default Html helper. Default Html helper displays ModelState value not Model.Just add `ModelState.Clear()` before you return Partial View:

```
public IActionResult CreateTasking(TaskingTemplateModel viewmodel)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    return PartialView("_TaskingTemplate", new TaskingTemplateModel { TaskingName = "test", TaskingTier = "Two", WorkItems = viewmodel.WorkItems }); 
}
```

Comment: haha. omg i just remembered running into this problem like 6 months ago, but it was on a different form. Yeah my custom html helpers are just using the default ones. Thank you very much

Comment: just did. Sorry about that